# Eclipse Juno with m2eclipse builds ear but omits war

Tags: eclipse, spring, maven, war, ear

I'm trying to build an application no one has touched in quite a while. It uses Spring and is an ear. The build environment is Eclipse Juno with Maven. When I build the app, an ear file is created but there is no war or other web resources in it. No web-inf folder.

if I go to the project -> properties -> Deployment Assembly there are mappings for source to deploy path, for example:

```
/src/main/java         WEB-INF/classes
/src/main/resources    WEB-INF/classes
/src/main/webapp       /
/src/test/java         WEB-INF/classes
/src/test/resources    WEB-INF/classes
```

The packaging type in the pom is set to ear.

What else do I need to check?

Comment: An EAR is an web application. Read this: http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/bnaby.html

Comment: Right, so I would expect to see the web resources in it, right?

Comment: Depending on the project and what it does, not necessarily